# WhatsAPI response

Tags: php, api, whatsapp

I'm trying to use the [WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI) library to send a message to a smartphone by a computer. I obtained the credential by using `mitmproxy` on a Linux Ubuntu computer, then I installed the certificate for an iPhone and I connected the iPhone on the same wi-fi network in which I've connected the Linux computer (I set up the network for use my proxy).

So I edited the file `whatsapp.php` (contained in Github package) with the credential I obtained in previous step and I started the service in a Shell to send a message to my phone in this way:

```
./whatsapp.php -s dest phone prova
```

when I press "enter" it began to work and I obtain the following:

```
[] Logging in as 'WhatsAPI Test' (from phone)
tx  <stream:features></stream:features>

tx  <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="WAUTH-2" user="from phone">??lg
               @*?*]?Z??ù?%??\?Z??Ǚ??R0??q??*???kX?L?Y%3????p>R-A_j'??ǯYN?1ƿ#t?$s?????ORLUG?dBvoI?</auth>

rx  <start from="s.whatsapp.net"></start>

rx  <stream:features></stream:features>

rx  <challenge>??2?a?
                     ?dxւ??㶄?</challenge>

tx  <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">u^?
)???4!???N?$+?H5??????Da?P</response>

rx  <success t="1396431143" kind="free" status="active" creation="1396347026" expiration="1427883026">???'17?,E??.??}??</success>

rx  <message from="dest phone@s.whatsapp.net" id="1396425196-49" retry="3" offline="3" type="text" t="1396431017" notify="Luca">
rx    <body>Prova</body>
rx  </message>

rx  <ib from="s.whatsapp.net">
rx    <offline count="1"></offline>
rx  </ib>

tx  <presence name="WhatsAPI Test"></presence>


[] Request last seen dest phone: tx  <iq to="dest phone@s.whatsapp.net" type="get" id="lastseen-1396431145-1" xmlns="jabber:iq:last">
tx    <query></query>
tx  </iq>

rx  <stream:error>
rx    <xml-not-well-formed></xml-not-well-formed>
rx  </stream:error>


[] Send message to dest phone: prova 
tx  <message to="dest phone@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="message-1396431150-2" t="1396431150">
tx    <x xmlns="jabber:x:event">
tx      <server></server>
tx    </x>
tx    <notify xmlns="urn:xmpp:whatsapp" name="WhatsAPI Test"></notify>
tx    <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
tx    <body>prova </body>
tx  </message>
```

I'm not understanding if the server has elaborated well my request or not, for now I din't receive any WhatsApp message on my smartphone. There's something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is quite old, however, would like to answer it.

Could make out in the below lines:

```
<message from="dest phone@s.whatsapp.net" id="1396425196-49" retry="3" offline="3" type="text" t="1396431017" notify="Luca">
rx    <body>Prova</body>
rx  </message>
```

you haven't changed the destination phone number which is why it shows

> message from="**dest phone**@s.whatsapp.net"

and also

> Request last seen dest phone: tx  iq to="**dest phone**@s.whatsapp.net"

Just input your destination phone number and your code should be working fine.

*P.S. WhatsApi do not support spam, hence, if you do so, your number would be blocked.*

Hope this helps.